# How would I get a Knockout Click binding to respect the Knockout Enable binding on non-form elements?

Tags: knockout.js

I have a `<span>` with a couple of bindings on it. `enable`, and `click`.

```
<span data-bind="enable: buttonEnabled, click: takeAnAction">Take An Action</span>
```

Is there a custom binding handler I could write, or another simple way of getting the `click` binding to respect (and not act) when the `enable` binding is false?

I know I can add an `if` statement in the `click` action, but it would be great if I could automate this action without adding the extra logic to my view.

Comment: The button should already be disabled based on the "enable" binding, so it will not run the handler.  Are you seeing an issue in a browser or do you have a jsFiddle?  http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/6N6tk/

Comment: Thanks for catching my mistake. I attempted to simplify my case and used a <button> which really works (didn't know until now). My actual code uses <span> tags. Here is an updated fiddle showing it as it happens to me: http://jsfiddle.net/6N6tk/2/. Changing to all <button>s is possible, I'm not sure yet.

Comment: If you are using something different than a button to simulate button's behavior than you have to take care of disabeling 'click' when node is inactive. Had to do by myself with DIVs as buttons in a project I've been previously

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you updated the question from the comment.  If you use a button or input element that supports being disabled, then this will work naturally for you.

If you did need to use something like a `span`, then you could write a quick custom binding to wrap it in a condition check like:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.clickIf = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
       var options = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()),
           wrappedHandler;

        if (options && options.condition && typeof options.action === "function") {
            wrappedHandler = function(data, event) {
               if (ko.utils.unwrapObservable(options.condition)) {
                  options.action.call(data, data, event);
               }
           };

           ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, { click: wrappedHandler });  
        }     
    }
};
```

You would use it like:

```
<span data-bind="clickIf: { action: test, condition: isEnabled }">Test</span>
```

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/LZTtE/

Comment: Thanks RP. I built on your solution and made something with a simpler data-bind syntax.

Comment: That is fine choice. My only concern (and reason for not suggesting it) would be that the actual `enable` binding is still being needlessly executed on element that cannot be disabled (not that it is realistically going to cause a performance issue).

Comment: Ha, you're right! Another pitfall of trying to simplify my example too much. I'm actually using a custom binding called `enabled` and doing some styling effects based on the value. Some of my controls use `enabled` with no `click` binding. So my custom `clickIfEnabled` is really tracking my other custom binding. Figuring out how to roll what I need from `enabled` into the stock `enable` binding is another story.

Answer (score 1):

Building on [RP Niemeyer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16550107/2004569). A simpler (but less extensible solution) is to reference the elements `enable` property directly in the custom binding handler.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.clickIfEnabled = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        var action = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()),
            wrappedHandler = function(data, event) {
               if (allBindingsAccessor().enable()) {
                  action.call(data, data, event);
               }
            };

        ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, { click: wrappedHandler });        
    }
};
```

Used like this:

```
<span data-bind="enable: isEnabled, clickIfEnabled: test">Test</span>
```

This method allows you to only change one standard binding. `click` to `clickIfEnabled`.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/LZTtE/6/

Answer (score 0):

RP Niemeyer's answer was a good start toward an extensible solution. However, **it does not allow you to include an *expression* containing observables** in the 'condition' option that will get reevaluated as those observables change over time.

For example, this binding only evaluates the 'condition' expression once (when the init callback executes), and does not work correctly as the value of the observables change:

```
<span data-bind="clickIf: { action: doSomething, condition: (isEnabled() == true && anotherObservable() == true) }">Test</span>
```

**In order for this binding to accept an *expression* containing observables, and properly execute based on the latest value of that expression, you'll need to restructure the binding handler like this:**

```
ko.bindingHandlers.clickIf = {

    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {        
        // Hold state of options so that the 'update' callback can effectively 
        // 'pass in' new evaluated 'condition' expressions (as observables change) to the wrappedHandler.
        element.ko_clickIfOptions = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());

        var wrappedHandler = function (data, event) {
            // "ko_clickIfOptions.condition" will get us the current value of a 'condition'
            //   expression since the 'update' callback updates these options            
            var condition = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(element.ko_clickIfOptions.condition);
            if (condition) {                
                element.ko_clickIfOptions.action.call(data, data, event);
            }
        };
        ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, { click: wrappedHandler });
    },
    // When the value of any observable in your expression changes, we grab 'options' 
    // again so that the wrappedHandler will have the latest value of the expression
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {        
        element.ko_clickIfOptions = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
    }
};
```

With this implementation, the example listed above operates correctly even as any of the observables in the 'condition' expression change.